# Is Mongrel2 still under active development?

Tags: mongrel

I hope this is the right exchange for this question. I noticed that the [mongrel2.org](http://mongrel2.org) site blog hasn't been updated since 2011. Does anyone know if the project itself is still under active development, or have the contributors/creators moved on to other things?

Comment: There is a big `contact` link on the site you linked. Why don't you just use it instead of asking this on a totally unrelated site?

Comment: Ah, maybe because this is where people go to ask questions. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I think you may need to read the FAQ to learn what questions should and should not be asked here.

Comment: And this question doesn't fit those criteria how, exactly? I read the FAQ, I figured this was the best fit 'exchange', and prefaced the question with a comment about hoping I'd found the right one. If not, kindly suggest the correct exchange and I'll happily request this question be moved there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes, it is. See this github page.](https://github.com/zedshaw/mongrel2/tree/develop)

I consider "last updated 3 days ago" to be under active development.